# using would for imaginary situations

Tags: grammar, would

Quote from a grammar book: "My parents are both teachers so you'd imagine I'd have no trouble at all academically."

I think using would in "I'd have no trouble...." is wrong because it is neither imaginary nor unlikely situation.  In other words, the speaker is not likely to have an academic trouble.

Please tell me whether I am right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case "you'd imagine I'd have no trouble at all academically." is hinting to the reader that the subject did have some troubles academically. You'd think he/she did not have academic troubles but you might be wrong.

For an example:
http://www.phrasemix.com/phrases/youd-think-that-something-would-do-or-be-something